# jQuery mobile UI listview

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I have simple question. I have made a very basic listview in jQuery mobile UI, but the borders are bugging and the background should be flat, but it's gradient.

Theme b is the standard jQuery mobile UI Theme Roller theme.

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6jQJ.png)

The code is as simple as this:

```
  <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b" data-inset="true">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h2>Level 1</h2>
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>RED Zone</li>
        <li>GREEN Zone</li>
        <li>PURPLE Zone</li>
        <li>GOLD Zone</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h2>Level 2</h2>
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>RED Zone</li>
        <li>GREEN Zone</li>
        <li>PURPLE Zone</li>
        <li>GOLD Zone</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h2>Level 3</h2>
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>RED Zone</li>
        <li>GREEN Zone</li>
        <li>PURPLE Zone</li>
        <li>GOLD Zone</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can't you just edit jquery.mobile-VERSION.css or set a new style for your listviews? add some styling information to your css and set data-role="listview mlistviewdesign", this sould do the job

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this solves it? Isn't it supposed to look like the theme roller? If I remove every css reference but jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css, I have perfect list with blue header and flat blue items. I want a light header, with gradient, and light grey items without gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply overwride your style by adding a new css or change your jquery.mobile.x.x.x.css file.

also see this thread [Styling jquery mobile listviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265465/styling-jquery-mobile-listviews?rq=1)

Comment: I can, but is that really the best solution? I thought I was able to use the themes. And what should I exactly override, right now I went for all 'li' tags.

Comment: You want to edit the style of your listview...so you have to either change your css or add a class containing your new style (which is the better solution).

Comment: What about the theme roller?